# Very unsafe-looking receptacle

Tags: electrical, receptacle, 240v, 120-240v

While I was searching for duplex receptacles where one was NEMA 5 (120V) and the other was NEMA 6 (240V), I found a few normal ones that were what I was looking for (Leviton 5031, 5842, 5844, Hubbell HBL5492I), as well as this horrifying abomination:

[image: Dangerous-looking receptacle]

I see two immediate problems with it:

1. It will accept both NEMA 5 and NEMA 6 plugs in the same receptacle, but a single receptacle can't operate on both of the required voltages.
2. The vertical slots are the same height, though I'm not sure whether they're both big or both small. If they're both small, then polarized plugs won't work at all in this. If they're both big, then it's even worse: polarized plugs could be plugged in the wrong way (although given point 1, depending how this is wired, there may not even be a "right" way).

Is there any possible way or place in which using this would be safe or legal? This seems even worse than the usual Chinese "junkstream" products, because those usually at least look okay in the picture.

Comment: I've seen very old ones  without the ground prong, but this is new.  Yes, I'd love to know the entomology of that particular little monster.  Entomology, *because it bugs me*.

Comment: Tell me you couldn't remove the tabs and have 120V at the top and 240V at the bottom.  Oh boy!!!

Comment: Now that's what I call a "convenience" outlet!  ...what a disaster that would/could be. I'll probably get snipped again for posting this. But I am going to research that outlet and see what's up with it. Terrible. idea. No way it's NEMA.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson nah, seconded on the outlet being a disaster in the making

Comment: Did you find this abomination lurking in the junkstream, or where did it turn up?

Comment: @JACK Yeah, you could do that. Then it would be "equivalent" in function to the Leviton 5842. Scary, since they wouldn't see a problem with it, but then as soon as someone else comes along and messes with the plugs, goodbye house.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Yep, the usual junkstream. When I searched for it, I saw it on the Amazon and Walmart marketplaces, as well as a bunch of "grow" sites. I'm deliberately not linking to them, but if you do a reverse image search, you'll see them all.

Answer (score 2):

I searched for this and couldn't find a NEMA code for this outlet (no surprise there!). But in my research it appears that this has been around for a long time, terrible idea as it was. Attached is a pic of a similar outlet that is obviously quite old.  There are actually 3 of them with the same configuration in the pic.  I would rather have made this a comment, than an answer, but pics can't be posted in comments.

[image: pics of old outlets]

Comment: Yeah, I've seen the two-prong version that you depict far left and far right before -- it's basically a 1-20T duplex receptacle.