# New 115v air conditioner burnt by a 240v outlet - is it fixable?

Tags: electrical, hvac

First I'd have to admit my own ignorance and did not notice an AC outlet in my house is 240v, before I plugged in a brand new 115v window unit only to destroy it. Is this broken AC fixable, typically/practically? I'd buy a new one and don't repeat the same mistake again - just want to know if I should recycle the broken one without hesitation or if it makes sense to try to fix it.

Comment: **Can you upload a picture of the receptacle?** 240V receptacles are supposed to have pin configurations that are incompatible with 120V appliances (and 120V receptacles incompatible with 240V appliances). But I have at least one receptacle in my house that is 120V but a strange dual design that could handle a 240V plug, so anything is possible. As far as fixing, that depends on how it failed. The bad news is that fuses protect against current, not voltage (and in fact fuses even in parts of devices designed for low voltage DC will often be rated at 250V!) so a lot of standard overcurrent

Comment: protection will prevent overloads from a short circuit but do little to protect against high voltage. You may have fried anything/everything from a simple power supply component to compressor/motor/etc. Hard to guess. In addition, an awful lot of consumer appliances are simply not designed to be repaired at the component level - to the extent that for many things a warranty "repair" is "send you another one and chalk it up to the cost of doing business".

Comment: Where are you located? That is, is it legal code where you are to have mixed 240 and 115 outlets which are plug-compatible?     In any case, unless you're very lucky you will at the very least have blown the input power converter on your A/C unit.   Does it have a set-switch on the back to select 115 vs. 220 input, by the way?

Comment: @manassehkatz, are you sure? 20 amp 120v looks similar to 240 but the horizontal pin is on the other side.

Comment: Thanks all for the quick comments! I'm in Boston with a 90 year old house (typical here, may sound ridiculous to other parts of the country), it has several 240 breakers while most of the rest are 110v. The receptacle I plugged into can accept the 115v plug... The AC doesn't have a set-switch. Based on the answers I think I'll just deal with it and recycle it!

Comment: @EdBeal I have a couple old barns with Hubbell US Pat. 1210176 double T receptacles. Fortunately 120v so error resistant.

Comment: @NoSparksPlease I have one in my house: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/188895/what-kind-of-receptacle-is-this

Comment: @EdBeal It looks similar. Grounding is the key. 15A - two vertical (120) or two horizontal (240) - no problem. 20A - one vertical + one horizontal - but grounding pin acts as an orientation key so no problem. Unless you either (a) have the crazy double T receptacle or (b) someone needed 240V and wired up a 120V receptacle not realizing that 240V has different receptacles.

Comment: Sorry I meant to comment and forgot about the non polarized versions. It is possible the neutral line was blown off on the controller. Since both are hot and your ac expected a neutral if may have just fried the wire it may be worth a look. Other than that it probably fried the control board but it’s worth a look to see if it can be fixed.

Comment: What makes you think the socket is 240V? Did it actually measure 240V across the conductors?  The mere fact the breaker is double does not necessarily mean that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nobody can tell you whether this should be repaired or discarded without opening it up and doing some diagnostics.   If you don't have the skills, try to find a friend who can.   Hopefully all you did is blow a fuse inside the unit, and you can replace it for 20 cents.   Can you remove the cover look for a fuse?    If you don't see one, then you can decide whether to keep trying, ask a friend for help or just throw it out.

Usually fuses inside devices are glass.  Let's hope.  Here is a blown glass fuse next to a good one.

[image]

Sometimes when a fuse like this blows it becomes so blackened you cannot see the broken conductor inside.  If you do see something that resembles one of these and are not sure you can add a picture to your question.

Comment: Sometimes you need a tester to check fuses,  have one fuse that looks good, but does not work.  Guessing connection broken inside cap.  Looks like the witonics picture.

Comment: Definitely worth a look. Problem is that fuses protect current, not voltage. But it is possible (especially with microcomputer controlled devices, which is "everything" these days) that 2x expected voltage could fry all kinds of stuff before a fuse would blow.

Comment: Although fuses blow on over current having the neutral to hot voltage 2x normal may blow a fuse, I might expect the neutral leg or trace to be blown open also but a fuse would be a good starting point.

Comment: I'm not sure where "fuses protect current" is meant to lead.  My hope for OP is that there is a fuse and that applying double the design voltage to the circuit will produce enough current to blow the fuse, and that this will happen before damage occurs to anything else.  Lots of wishful thinking but it is indeed the overcurrent function of the fuse we hope to exploit.  It's possible that with the unit power switch in "off", the fan and compressor motors are disengaged but there are still electronics connected to the input that could fry without popping the fuse.  One way to find out .....

Comment: @crip659 I'm afraid you're right.  Sometimes these things are ceramic.  Seemed better to keep the answer simple in this case.  Get OP to open the thing up, have a looksie and report.  Better than resorting directly to the trash I think.